# spring boot actuator health endpoint + dynamic resilience4j circuit breakers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, resilience4j

I have a spring boot app, which uses [resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j) AOP-based [`@CircuitBreaker`](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#section-annotations)s.

Now I would like to make the circuit breakers' information available in the `/actuator/health` endpoint, but I'm not seeing the `details.circuitBtreakers` objects [described in the docs](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#section-health-endpoint) in the JSON output.

#### What am I doing wrong?

---

By comparison, getting dynamic cache information to appear in the `/actuator/metrics` endpoint required a small amount of custom wiring, but this is [well documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-metrics-cache). I wonder if there is a similar trick that I can apply for dynamically defined `@CircuitBreaker`s to be registerd with the `/actuator/health` endpoint.

**`MyService.java`:**

```java
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;
    @Autowired
    private CacheMetricsRegistrar cacheMetricsRegistrar;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        // On-the-fly defined (annotation-based) caches are not auto-registered with micrometer metrics.
        final Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("myCache");
        cacheMetricsRegistrar.bindCacheToRegistry(cache);
    }

    @CircuitBreaker(name = "myCB", fallbackMethod = "fallbackCallAnApi")
    public String callAnApi() throws RestClientException {
        // ...
    }

    @Cacheable("myCache")
    public String getSomethingCacheable() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**`application.properties`:**

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.registerHealthIndicator=true
management.endpoints.web.expose=health,metrics
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,metrics
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
management.metrics.enable.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.calls=true
management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamically registering CircuitBreakers for the HealthIndicator endpoint doesn't work at the moment.
Unfortunately you have to configure them:

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
    configs:
        default:
            registerHealthIndicator: true
    instances:
        myCB:
            baseConfig: default
```

You could say it's a bug.

https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/blob/master/resilience4j-spring-boot2/src/main/java/io/github/resilience4j/circuitbreaker/monitoring/health/CircuitBreakersHealthIndicator.java#L99-L102

Comment: The docs (and your answer here) show how to configure them, but what are the endpoints? https://<host>/actuator/health/circuitbreaker(s) is not working. I've guessed at a few other permutations but not successfully so far.

Comment: ../actuator/health just shows status=OK, even though I have configured both management.health.circuitbreakers.enabled=true and resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.registerHealthIndicator=true

Answer (score 2):

Late but sure.
With HTTP you need an extra configuration.

```
management:
  security:
    enabled:false
  health:
    circuitbreakers:
      enabled: true
  endpoint:
    health:
      show-details: "ALWAYS"
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"

resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
    configs:
        default:
           registerHealthIndicator: true
```